# Calculate percentage across multiple files with awk

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, echo

I have 100 csv files like:

```
file_city_1 file_city_2 file_city_3 file_city_4
```

City name is variable, there is 25 cities, each city has 4 region. Each of the 4 region contain some statistics like:

```
parameter1 : number1
parameter1 : number2
.....
parameter50 : number50
```

So I should calculate each region's each parameter percentage in city total for this parameter. So what I want to do is something something like:

```
file_city_parameter1_total = parameter1_region1 + parameter1_region2 + parameter1_region3 + parameter1_region4
```

Then calculate percentage for this specific parameter for each region:

```
file_city_region_parameter1_percentage = parameter1_region1 / file_city_parameter1_total * 100
```

then echo all parameters percentage over total (sum of 4 regions) for a specific region and should do it for regions (all 100 files)

I actually tried multiple codes but I don't want to paste them here as they are way long to read. I defined all parameters separately for each region, parameters, tried different command substitution and nested loop. But stuck at some point. So I'm wondering what is the easiest way to accomplish this work done with awk, grep, sed or anything else.

Thanks.

Comment: How are the regions separated?

Comment: Do you really need to do this with AWK? It's certainly possible but it would probably be easier with Ruby or Perl.

Comment: As perreal write in your other question, you should use `associative array`

Comment: DarkDust I am not very proficient with Perl neither Ruby so I try to accomplish with shell. But I am on the way to learn Pyhton. I will use it after a while for new projects.

Comment: Well, since you're not very proficient with AWK either (no offense), you might want to opt for Python instead. You can solve this with AWK's associate arrays (which behave like maps/dictionaries) if you really want to, though... I just think it's an unnecessarily hard to use tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
#! /bin/bash

cities=(city1 city2) #list the 25 cities here

for ((i=0; i<${#cities[@]}; i++)) ; do
    city="${cities[$i]}"
    awk -F: -f a.awk ${city}_1 ${city}_2 ${city}_3 ${city}_4 ${city}_1 ${city}_2 ${city}_3 ${city}_4
done
```

where `a.awk` is:

```
ARGIND <= 4 {
    sub(/[[:blank:]]+/,"")
    if ($0)
        a[$1]+=$2
    next
}
{
    savename=FILENAME "_avg"
    sub(/[[:blank:]]+/,"")
    if ($0)
        print $1 " : " ($2/a[$1])*100 > savename
}
```

this will produce 100 files, city1_1_avg, city1_2_avg, city1_3_avg, city1_4_avg, city2_1_avg, .. with the region averages of the parameters..

Comment: How should we declare this a.awk function?